# Taking only the center peaks from Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I have a clock image. I want to find the time on that clock.

[image: here]

I'm doing Hough Transform to find the lines (hands of the clock).

[image: here]

Now what I need is only those lines which are close to the centre of the clock, as they will be the clock hands.**

How to do it in MATLAB?

Comment: I suggest you mask the image first with a circular mask.

Comment: Try estimating the center. You can use the fact that the lines point toward the center.

Comment: This is just such a perfect image, it's trivial to binarize and find the hand endpoints and get those angles. No need for Hough at all. Is the purpose of this exercise to learn about Hough, or to read the time on a clock? If the latter, is this example image representative of a real situation?